# Drawing trees from above

Tags: background, drawing

I'm working on an animation background which involves a high angle shot of a forest. I searched on internet to hunt some references for the trees and other foliage from such an angle. I could only find real photos or fully rendered paintings and what I drew from those didn't seem right. So I went to my faculty for support, he asked me to keep hunting for references. Now after growing tired of looking through the same images I've come here to seek help. I'm looking for a link to a webpage that will have a tutorial for it or even a reference image of a drawing.

Thank you!

Comment: Like this? http://videohive.net/item/aerial-tree-top-fly-over/11308872  Keywords "stock footage aerial shot tree" and use some filter to make it look like an animation. I don't think animations are part of the Graphic Design Stack Exchange topics but I gave you helpful keywords to look for animations, footage and tutorials.

Comment: I was looking for drawing segment of stack exchange, I found a description for drawing in Graphic Design so hence I put it here, apologies if it was mistake

Comment: There's no mistake. My suggestion wasn't really what you needed and you got a better answer, and accepted it. Everything is working as intended!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider looking into architectural illustrations as a possible source of ideas for this. A quick Google Image Search using, "**Architecture illustration aerial**" found these, and others, as results. Thinking this is the type of stuff you're after though you didn't give any example so could be entirely wrong:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SwapnilRastogi thanks, if you feel this answers your question please mark it correct. Helps the site stay organized when people are searching Unanswered Questions

Answer (score 0):

The intro to The Shining has a few nice overhead shots of forests. The lighting is a little extreme, but maybe there's something there you can use for reference. Here's a 1080p clip of it: https://youtu.be/kiV3J_e977Q?t=20s